# read single message from bag-file (c++)

Tags: ros, rosbag, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,I'm new to this whole ROS stuff and have a problem which I can't solve on my own.

I want to read a single message from a given bag-file using c++11. To do this I read the short tutorial and cookbook for rosbag.
I get the message with iterating over all messages in the bag. But I want to know if there is a way to direct get the specified message (data)? The topic (m.getTopic()), timestamp (m.getTime()) and the structure of the message (m.MessageDefinition()) is known.

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227800/read-single-message-from-bag-file-(c++)/) by [Duke](https://answers.ros.org/users/26109/duke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I dont know for sure what the best solution to your problem is. But just to brainstorm things you might try (I have not tried these myself):
Perhaps you could use the filter functionality to make a new bag file containing only the messages you care about. Another option would be to use cut.py script from bag_tools (https://github.com/srv/srv_tools/blob/indigo/bag_tools/scripts/cut.py). Those would be more "direct" in that you would write fewer lines of codes, but I am not sure that it would be any faster than what you are doing now.

If you need a faster solution the bag file format supports random access. Assuming the bag file is in chronological order you could make a function that does a binary search to find the message you care about.

---

Originally posted by [vaziri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26088/vaziri/) with karma: 46 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Duke](https://answers.ros.org/users/26109/duke/) on 2016-03-01**:
thanks for your answer. I think the filter functionality also iterates over the whole bag and looking for one element is already a kind of filter. its working but it feels not right to search the whole file just to get one special element.

**Comment by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) on 2017-03-16**:
did you make it?